# Bootstrap Navbar Pop up form

Tags: html

I'm developing a simple website to show some random information and I need to open a pop-up form to login and register a user when I click on the login link on the navbar! How can I make it?

This is what the website looks like now!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbxWB.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can go with bootstrap modal for popup, Here  is sample example which is written in bootstrap3 for more detail or for latest version you  can check the below [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Anchor-->
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up Form</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Form Content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```